# How do I pipe a heredoc?

Tags: pipelining

I have some strings in `$o1` and `$o2` that I want to tabulate.

I saw a post on here saying to do this but it doesn't work ( `Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")`).

```
{
cat <<EndOfOutput
$o1
$o2
EndOfOutput
} | column
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the output of the code you tried? Also, your question could benefit from some basic information. While some people may understand what a "heredoc" is and make further assumptions regarding the nature of your question, it may be helpful to explain you're dealing with BASH and then specify the OS, and perhaps some details on the strings that your variables represent.

Comment: Have you consider using `printf` command?

Comment: `printf` would be very difficult to use. I just want to run it through `column` to make it line up.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you do it literally like in your post.

You have to keep in mind that heredoc terminators **cannot be indented** unless the heredoc is started using `<<-EndOfOutput` (the dash indicates that all leading tabs – not any whitespace, but only tabs – should be stripped).

| Works | Also works | Fails | Works with tabs only |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ``` { cat <<End $o1 $o2 End } | column ``` | ``` { cat <<End $o1 $o2 End } | column ``` | ``` { cat <<End $o1 $o2 End } | column ``` | ``` { cat <<-End $o1 $o2 End } | column ``` |

So the version you've posted without any indentation actually works perfectly fine on all shells; it's when you indent it to look nice that you would get the error.

Of course, you could save you some trouble by not using the brackets (the heredoc can be opened in the middle of a line) – or, by not having a pipe in there at all:

| Works | Works | Works |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` cat <<End | column $o1 $o2 End ``` | ``` column <<EndOfOutput $o1 $o2 EndOfOutput ``` | ``` <<EndOfOutput column $o1 $o2 EndOfOutput ``` |

(Heredocs are a shell-syntax feature so they don't require `cat` specifically.)

Comment: What I have posted **doesn't** work.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
column -t <<EOF
$o1
$o2
EOF
```